# MVC: Custom, fluent Html Helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm writing a custom HTML helper to display a Grid and I'm focussing myself on Telerik and other parties for the syntax I would like to use.

I have a model with 3 properties (Name, DateUpdated and DateCreted) and an IEnumerable of that one is passed to my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<GridPageFolderViewModel>
```

Then I have my static HtmlHelperExtensions class:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    #region Grid

    public static GridBuilder<TModelEntry> GridFor<TModel, TModelEntry>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, TModelEntry model)
    {
        return new GridBuilder<TModelEntry>();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This class does return a GridBuilder which looks as the following:

```
public class GridBuilder<TModel> : IGridBuilder
{
    #region Properties

    private string name { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public GridBuilder<TModel> WithColumns(Action<ColumnBuilder<TModel>> function)
    {
        return this;
    } 

    internal MvcHtmlString Render()
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString("This is a value.");
    }

    #endregion

    #region IGridBuilder Members

    public GridBuilder<TModel> Name(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;

        return this;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IHtmlString Members

    public string ToHtmlString()
    { return Render().ToHtmlString(); }

    #endregion
}
```

And then I have my ColumnBuilder class.

```
public class ColumnBuilder<TModel>
{
    public void Bind<TItem>(Func<TModel, TItem> func)
    {

    }
}
```

With all this code into place (nothing is rendered at this point), I can use the following syntax:

```
@(Html.GridFor(new GridPageFolderViewModel())
      .Name("PageOverviewGrid")
      .WithColumns(column =>
      {
          column.Bind(c => c.Name);
          column.Bind(c => c.DateCreated);
          column.Bind(c => c.DateUpdated);
      }
)
```

The 'problem' here is that I need to specify the type of object that a single item in the Grid is holding (the GridPageFolderViewModel), otherwise, I cannot access the properties in the column binder code.

Anyone has some advice on how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might be interested in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774228/MVC-Html-Table-Helper-Part-Display-Tables) which take a different approach to building tables with a HtmlHelper using attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the link but unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for ...

Comment: @Complexity Hi I am understanding your code and it seems very nice but I have one question regarding rendering, where have you written your logic for rendering the columns of Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the view model is `IEnumerable<GridPageFolderViewModel>`, you just need to declare your helper like this:

```
public static GridBuilder<TModelEntry> GridFor<TModelEntry>(this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModelEntry>> htmlHelper)
{
    return new GridBuilder<TModelEntry>();
}
```

It would mean your helper can only be used on views where the model is an `IEnumerable<T>`, but I think that makes sense.

Now in your view you can do:

```
@(Html.GridFor()
      .Name("PageOverviewGrid")
      .WithColumns(column =>
      {
          column.Bind(c => c.Name);
          column.Bind(c => c.DateCreated);
          column.Bind(c => c.DateUpdated);
      }
)
```

PS. Don't worry if you need to access the model inside your helper. You can still retrieve it from `htmlHelper.ViewData.Model`, which will be nicely typed as `IEnumerable<TModelEntry>`

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'll review it and come back to you. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm. Quite easy once you know the solutions. I have some other questions regarding best practices aswell, but I'll place them on codereview :-)